# compile dlib with cuda

Tags: dlib

I am trying to compile dlib with cuda. I clone the repository from this GitHub link https://github.com/davisking/dlib and then tried to run

```
python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
```

But I receive an error. Can anyone help me to solve it?

[image]

Comment: 4th line of your screenshoot mentions some error log, probably it may contain more information.

Comment: Hi I have checked CMakeOutput.log. there is only one line: "The system is: Windows - 10.0.16299 - AMD64"

Comment: Probably it requires cmake and some c++ compiler installed, as per instructions on http://dlib.net/compile.html

Answer (score 11):

Create a folder for host the source

```
mkdir -p /opt/SP/packages/
cd $_
```

Clone the repository

```
git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
cd dlib
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Create a folder for build the software (cmake have to be installed)

```
mkdir build
cd $_
```

Now run cmake with the following options:

```
cmake  -D DLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -D USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1 ../
```

[If everything is fine, you can see a similar output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC8va.png)

*NOTE: Install **cuDNN**, openblas and **Intel MKL/BLAS/LAPACK** if your system is compliant with them.*

Link to Intel Performance Library: https://software.seek.intel.com/performance-libraries

Link to cuDNN: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

Now you can compile the source with

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

After these step, the source is compiled.

Now you can install the python API.

```
cd ../
python setup.py install
```

NOTE: The compilation this time will use all the available CPU, be sure that you have enough memory for compile.

Once completed, you can query your python packages for be sure that dlib is now installed:

[pip freeze | grep dlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xNA8.png)

For check if the installation was succesfully:

[Open a terminal and run the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgRzV.png)

```
>>> import dlib.cuda as cuda;
>>> print(cuda.get_num_devices());
1
>>> import dlib
>>> dlib.DLIB_USE_BLAS
True
>>> dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA
True
>>> dlib.DLIB_USE_LAPACK
True
```

Comment: I followed your instruction, and got on the `python setup.py install` - `    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.` Although, it did not show any issue on the config part. Any idea how I got that ?

Comment: You need to share the complete log of the building execution

Comment: I made a question with it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045773/dlib-build-with-cuda-failed-win-10

Answer (score 3):

Steps which you should take care, note that the solution I am giving here is general. It will work with all the users.
Download latest version of dlib from official site (current is dlib 19.15).

1. Check your Ubuntu/Mint version. If you are using bionic then you should download cuda10 and cudnn for cuda 10. Artful and Xenial can go with cuda 9.
2. Install the latest version of CMake i.e. 3.12.x (current). Otherwise you may get some errors like

   > CUDA_cublas_device_LIBRARY (ADVANCED) " etc.
3. If you want to install dlib with cuda support in python2 then the command is:

   ```
   sudo python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --yes DLIB_USE_CUDA
   ```

   and for python3 the command is:

   ```
   sudo python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --yes DLIB_USE_CUDA
   ```
4. You may get an error like `python.h not found`. So for that you can use the following commands :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python3-dev or sudo apt-get install python2-dev
   ```

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev python-numpy
   ```
5. Success!!!

If you are working on Anaconda then just copy the content of

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages

and paste it in

> /home/Your_computer's_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages

BOOM! You are good to go!