# Building dlib (for face_recognition) with CUDA support without Visual Studio (Python, Windows)

Tags: python, visual-studio, face-recognition

I am using: Windows 10, Nvidia GTX 1060, Python3, Visual Studio 2017

I would like to use my GPU in order to do real-time face recognition with Python. After some research I found out that you have to install dlib with CUDA support. I have installed CUDA 9.2.

I tried to build dlib with CMake and CUDA like described here: [compile dlib with cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731346/compile-dlib-with-cuda)

It raised an error, saying that Visual Studio 2017 (which I had installed) needed to run in "64-bit mode".

Is there any way to build dlib with CUDA support for Windows, without having to use Visual Studio at all? If so, how? If not, what do I do?

Is there a pre-built version of dlib with CUDA?

Comment: The CUDA toolchain for windows requires Visual Studio. Non negotiable requirement