# Dlib build with cuda failed (win 10)

Tags: python, compilation, anaconda, dlib

I tried to install dlib's python API, first compilation works:
here are the details logs but I get an error whenever I try to launch setup.py

First, I managed to do :

`cmake  -D DLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -D USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1 ../`

Then :

`cmake --build . --config Release`

[(output are available here)](https://pastebin.com/EYrWtgN6)

And finally

activate my conda env:
`conda activate face`

`python setup.py install`

get me this output :

```
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib>conda activate face

(face) D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing tools/python\dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'tools/python\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'
adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
writing manifest file 'tools/python\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.6.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 16 2021, 11:37:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -A x64'
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30037.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30037.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: D:/Program Files (x86)/Anaconda/envs/face/python.exe (found version "3.6.13") 
-- Found PythonLibs: D:/Program Files (x86)/Anaconda/envs/face/libs/Python36.lib
-- pybind11 v2.2.4
-- Using CMake version: 3.20.3
-- Compiling dlib version: 19.22.99
-- SSE4 instructions can be executed by the host processor.
-- AVX instructions can be executed by the host processor.
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Enabling AVX instructions
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1 (found suitable version "10.1", minimum required is "7.5") 
-- Looking for cuDNN install...
-- Found cuDNN: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1/lib/x64/cudnn.lib
-- Building a CUDA test project to see if your compiler is compatible with CUDA...
-- Building a cuDNN test project to check if you have the right version of cuDNN installed...
-- Enabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL USE CUDA
-- C++11 activated.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/users/Felix/Documents/Python Script 2/_install/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release
Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- /m'
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.10.1+2fd48ab73 pour .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

  Checking Build System
  Building NVCC (Device) object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/Release/dlib_generated_cuda_dlib.cu.obj
  cuda_dlib.cu
  cuda_dlib.cu
  Building NVCC (Device) object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/Release/dlib_generated_cusolver_dlibapi.cu.obj
  cusolver_dlibapi.cu
  cusolver_dlibapi.cu
  Building Custom Rule D:/users/Felix/Documents/Python Script 2/_install/dlib/dlib/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake is re-running because D:/users/Felix/Documents/Python Script 2/_install/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release/dlib_build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is out-of-date.
    the file 'D:/users/Felix/Documents/Python Script 2/_install/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release/dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/dlib_generated_cuda_dlib.cu.obj.depend'
    is newer than 'D:/users/Felix/Documents/Python Script 2/_install/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release/dlib_build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp.depend'
    result='-1'
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
  -- pybind11 v2.2.4
  -- Using CMake version: 3.20.3
  -- Compiling dlib version: 19.22.99
  -- SSE4 instructions can be executed by the host processor.
  -- AVX instructions can be executed by the host processor.
  -- Enabling AVX instructions
  -- Looking for cuDNN install...
  -- Found cuDNN: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1/lib/x64/cudnn.lib
  -- Enabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL USE CUDA
  -- C++11 activated.
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: D:/users/Felix/Documents/Python Script 2/_install/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release
  base64_kernel_1.cpp
  bigint_kernel_1.cpp
  bigint_kernel_2.cpp
  bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp
  entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp
  entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp
  entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp
  entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp
  fonts.cpp
  md5_kernel_1.cpp
  tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp
  unicode.cpp
  test_for_odr_violations.cpp
  sockets_kernel_1.cpp
  bsp.cpp
  dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp
  dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp
  dir_nav_extensions.cpp
  linker_kernel_1.cpp
  extra_logger_headers.cpp
  logger_kernel_1.cpp
  logger_config_file.cpp
  misc_api_kernel_1.cpp
  misc_api_kernel_2.cpp
  sockets_extensions.cpp
  sockets_kernel_2.cpp
  sockstreambuf.cpp
  sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp
  server_kernel.cpp
  server_iostream.cpp
  server_http.cpp
  multithreaded_object_extension.cpp
  threaded_object_extension.cpp
  threads_kernel_1.cpp
  threads_kernel_2.cpp
  threads_kernel_shared.cpp
  thread_pool_extension.cpp
  async.cpp
  timer.cpp
  stack_trace.cpp
  cpu_dlib.cpp
  tensor_tools.cpp
  image_dataset_metadata.cpp
  mnist.cpp
  cifar.cpp
  global_function_search.cpp
  kalman_filter.cpp
  auto.cpp
  widgets.cpp
  drawable.cpp
  canvas_drawing.cpp
  style.cpp
  base_widgets.cpp
  gui_core_kernel_1.cpp
  gui_core_kernel_2.cpp
  png_loader.cpp
  save_png.cpp
  jpeg_loader.cpp
  save_jpeg.cpp
  cudnn_dlibapi.cpp
  cublas_dlibapi.cpp
  curand_dlibapi.cpp
  cuda_data_ptr.cpp
  gpu_data.cpp
  arm_init.c
  filter_neon_intrinsics.c
  png.c
  pngerror.c
  pngget.c
  pngmem.c
  pngpread.c
  pngread.c
  pngrio.c
  pngrtran.c
  pngrutil.c
  pngset.c
  pngtrans.c
  pngwio.c
  pngwrite.c
  pngwtran.c
  pngwutil.c
  adler32.c
  compress.c
  crc32.c
  deflate.c
  gzclose.c
  gzlib.c
  gzread.c
  gzwrite.c
  infback.c
  inffast.c
  inflate.c
  inftrees.c
  trees.c
  uncompr.c
  zutil.c
  jaricom.c
  jcapimin.c
  jcapistd.c
  jcarith.c
  jccoefct.c
  jccolor.c
  jcdctmgr.c
  jchuff.c
  jcinit.c
  jcmainct.c
  jcmarker.c
  jcmaster.c
  jcomapi.c
  jcparam.c
  jcprepct.c
  jcsample.c
  jdapimin.c
  jdapistd.c
  jdarith.c
  jdatadst.c
  jdatasrc.c
  jdcoefct.c
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\dlib\external\libjpeg\jdatadst.c(185,60): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'unsigned long', perte possible de données [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
  jdcolor.c
  jddctmgr.c
  jdhuff.c
  jdinput.c
  jdmainct.c
  jdmarker.c
  jdmaster.c
  jdmerge.c
  jdpostct.c
  jdsample.c
  jerror.c
  jfdctflt.c
  jfdctfst.c
  jfdctint.c
  jidctflt.c
  jidctfst.c
  jidctint.c
  jmemmgr.c
  jmemnobs.c
  jquant1.c
  jquant2.c
  jutils.c
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\dlib\external\libjpeg\jerror.c(193,5): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp
.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\dlib\external\libjpeg\jerror.c(195,5): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp 
.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(307,53): warning C4267: '+=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'long', perte possible de données [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(367,70): warning C4267: '+=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'long', perte possible de données [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(977,46): warning C4267: '-=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'long', perte possible de données [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(991,46): warning C4267: '-=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'long', perte possible de données [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(1107,19): warning C4996: 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\te 
mp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(1110,11): warning C4996: 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\tem 
p.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
  dlib.vcxproj -> D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\dlib_build\Release\dlib19.22.99_release_64bit_msvc1929.lib
  Building Custom Rule D:/users/Felix/Documents/Python Script 2/_install/dlib/tools/python/CMakeLists.txt
  dlib.cpp
  matrix.cpp
  vector.cpp
  svm_c_trainer.cpp
  svm_rank_trainer.cpp
  decision_functions.cpp
  other.cpp
  basic.cpp
  cca.cpp
  sequence_segmenter.cpp
  svm_struct.cpp
  image.cpp
  image2.cpp
  image3.cpp
  image4.cpp
  rectangles.cpp
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\other.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.w
in-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\svm_c_trainer.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\buil 
d\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\image.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.w 
in-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\svm_struct.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\t 
emp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\matrix.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp. 
win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\vector.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp. 
win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\rectangles.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\t 
emp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\basic.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.w 
in-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\image3.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp. 
win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\sequence_segmenter.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib 
\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\dlib.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.wi
n-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\svm_rank_trainer.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\b 
uild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\cca.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.win 
-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\decision_functions.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib 
\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\image4.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp. 
win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\image2.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp. 
win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
  object_detection.cpp
  shape_predictor.cpp
  correlation_tracker.cpp
  face_recognition.cpp
  cnn_face_detector.cpp
  global_optimization.cpp
  image_dataset_metadata.cpp
  numpy_returns.cpp
  line.cpp
  gui.cpp
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\object_detection.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\b
uild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\correlation_tracker.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dli
b\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\shape_predictor.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\bu 
ild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\cnn_face_detector.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\
build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\face_recognition.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\b
uild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\global_optimization.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dli
b\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\gui.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.win
-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\image_dataset_metadata.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\
dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\numpy_returns.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\buil
d\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\Library\include\gif_lib.h(286,61): error C2734: 'GifAsciiTable8x8' : un objet const doit être initialisé s'il n'est pas 'extern' (compilation du fichier source D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\tools\python\src\line.cpp) [D:\users\Felix\Documents\Python Script 2\_install\dlib\build\temp.wi
n-amd64-3.6\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 164, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 150, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 134, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "setup.py", line 174, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\envs\face\lib\subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

This last operation did not work well.

I'm on windows 10, dlib 19.22, anaconda 4.10

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to activate the environment and verify in `cmake` is installed?

Comment: `conda activate face` then `cmake -version` get `cmake version 3.20.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).`